# Criar nova coluna no data frame dividindo os valores de uma coluna por uma linha anterior no R

Tags: r

Estou tentando adicionar uma nova coluna em um data frame que divide a linha seguinte pela linha anterior

Esse é meu data frame:

|  | Open | High | Low | Close | Adj.Close | Volume |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 60227 | 66594 | 59371 | 64671 | 64671 | 60057300 |
| 2 | 64687 | 69488 | 63740 | 66662 | 66662 | 56775200 |
| 3 | 66661 | 67398 | 62496 | 64984 | 64984 | 73694400 |
| 4 | 64989 | 66211 | 62826 | 65403 | 65403 | 51935600 |
| 5 | 65404 | 68792 | 60315 | 62711 | 62711 | 86770000 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

O código que estou tentando é o seguinte:

```
i <- 1
  
while (i<=5) {
  
  IBOV["RETORNO MENSAL"] <- IBOV$Adj.Close[i+1]/ IBOV$Adj.Close[i]
  i<- i+1

}
```

Entretanto ele cria uma coluna com Valores "NA"

---

### Dados em formato `dput`

```
IBOV <-
structure(list(Open = c(60227, 64687, 66661, 64989, 65404), 
High = c(66594L, 69488L, 67398L, 66211L, 68792L), 
Low = c(59371L, 63740L, 62496L, 62826L, 60315L), 
Close = c(64671L, 66662L, 64984L, 65403L, 62711L), 
Adj.Close = c(64671L, 66662L, 64984L, 65403L, 62711L), 
Volume = c(60057300L, 56775200L, 73694400L, 51935600L, 86770000L)), 
row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode-se escrever uma função vetorizada para calcular os retornos de qualquer vetor. Depois aplica-se a função à coluna que se pretende.

```
retornos <- function(x, default = NA){
  if(length(x) < 2) {
    default[seq_along(x)]
  } else {
    y <- x[-1]/x[-length(x)]
    c(default, y)
  }
}

retornos(IBOV$Adj.Close)
#[1]        NA 1.0307866 0.9748282 1.0064477 0.9588398

retornos(IBOV$Adj.Close, default = 0)
#[1] 0.0000000 1.0307866 0.9748282 1.0064477 0.9588398

IBOV$RETORNO_MENSAL <- retornos(IBOV$Adj.Close, default = 0)

IBOV
#   Open  High   Low Close Adj.Close   Volume RETORNO_MENSAL
#1 60227 66594 59371 64671     64671 60057300      0.0000000
#2 64687 69488 63740 66662     66662 56775200      1.0307866
#3 66661 67398 62496 64984     64984 73694400      0.9748282
#4 64989 66211 62826 65403     65403 51935600      1.0064477
#5 65404 68792 60315 62711     62711 86770000      0.9588398
```

Answer (score 1):

```
IBOV$RETORNO_MENSAL = 0

i=1
while (i < nrow(IBOV)) {
  
  IBOV$RETORNO_MENSAL[i] <- IBOV$Adj.Close[i+1]/ IBOV$Adj.Close[i]
  i <- i+1

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode dividir diretamente pela coluna deslocada para frente:

```
IBOV <- within(IBOV, `RETORNO MENSAL` <- Adj.Close/c(NA, Adj.Close[-nrow(IBOV)]))
```

O pacote dplyr tem as funções `lag` e `lead` para esses casos:

```
library(dplyr)

IBOV <- IBOV %>% mutate(`RETORNO MENSAL` = Adj.Close/lag(Adj.Close))
```

O pacote data.table tem a função `shift`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(IBOV)

IBOV[, `RETORNO MENSAL` := Adj.Close/shift(Adj.Close)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é utilizar em conjunto as funções [`head()` e `tail()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2/topics/head) do pacote [*utils*](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/utils/versions/3.6.2) e [`nrow()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/nrow) do pacote [`base`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2)

- A função `head()` obtém os primeiros elementos de um *vetor*, *matriz*, *tabela*, *dataframe* ou *função*.
- A função `tail()` obtém os últimos elementos de um *vetor*, *matriz*, *tabela*, *dataframe* ou *função*.
- A função `nrow()` retorna o número de linhas presentes num *vetor*, *matriz* ou *dataframe*.

```r
IBOV <- structure(
  list(
    Open = c(60227, 64687, 66661, 64989, 65404), 
    High = c(66594L, 69488L, 67398L, 66211L, 68792L), 
    Low = c(59371L, 63740L, 62496L, 62826L, 60315L), 
    Close = c(64671L, 66662L, 64984L, 65403L, 62711L), 
    Adj.Close = c(64671L, 66662L, 64984L, 65403L, 62711L), 
    Volume = c(60057300L, 56775200L, 73694400L, 51935600L, 86770000L)
  ), 
  row.names = c(NA, -5L), 
  class = "data.frame"
)


IBOV["RETORNO MENSAL"] <- c(0,
     tail(IBOV$Adj.Close, nrow(IBOV)-1)/
     head(IBOV$Adj.Close, nrow(IBOV)-1)
)

print(IBOV)
```

```
   Open  High   Low Close Adj.Close   Volume RETORNO MENSAL
1 60227 66594 59371 64671     64671 60057300      0.0000000
2 64687 69488 63740 66662     66662 56775200      1.0307866
3 66661 67398 62496 64984     64984 73694400      0.9748282
4 64989 66211 62826 65403     65403 51935600      1.0064477
5 65404 68792 60315 62711     62711 86770000      0.9588398
```

<sup>Teste o código no [Repl.it](https://replit.com/@Augusto-Vasques/RetornoMensal#main.r)</sup>